# How can I view long logs in AWS cloudwatch with ...more in the end?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

The screenshot below shows a long log with multiple "... xx more". I kind of got stuck debugging an issue so I need more details about the error. Is it possible to expand it in AWS Cloudwatch?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. It seems like a raw log message.